Can ACEMD be implemented with OpenPathSampling
Is it possible to implement ACEMD with OPS? I am asking in the context of using NNP/MM models with OPS. The paper "NNP/MM: Accelerating Molecular Dynamics Simulations with
Machine Learning Potentials and Molecular Mechanics" uses OpenMM and OpenMM-Torch  through ACEMD.
Since OPS supports OpenMM, can ACEMD also be used (since it appears to use OpenMM as the MD engine)?

+1 one and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!!

Thank you for the welcome!
